# how to properly setup phabricator diffusion to mirror my git repo

Tags: git, phabricator

I try to setup diffusion to host my existing git repo, and just as a mirror to it.

I use Diffusion -> new repository -> Create a New Hosted Repository -> ... -> Configure More Options First

Then I add a mirror in Mirrors in More Options to my existing git remote repo, and activate the diffusion repo.

After a couple of time, all the branches in my remote repo are removed!

And the daemon.log says:

```
 [/opt/phabricator/src/applications/repository/daemon/PhabricatorRepositoryPullLocalDaemon.php:374]
[04-Jul-2015 13:18:14 Asia/Shanghai] [2015-07-04 13:18:14] PHLOG: 'Unexpected output while updating repository "r
TEST": [2015-07-04 13:18:14] EXCEPTION: (PhutilProxyException) Error while pushing "TEST" repository to mirrors.
{>} (PhutilAggregateException) Exceptions occurred while mirroring the "TEST" repository.
    - CommandException: Command failed with error #1!
      COMMAND
      git push --verbose --mirror -- 'xxxxx'

      STDOUT
      (empty)

      STDERR
      Pushing to https://xxxxx@git.oschina.net/onefi/treehole-game.git
      POST git-receive-pack (158 bytes)
      remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
      remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
      remote: error:
      remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
      remote: error: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
      remote: error: current branch, with or without a warning message.
  ...' at [/opt/phabricator/src/applications/repository/daemon/PhabricatorRepositoryPullLocalDaemon.php:374]
```

I am just confused what to do. I accidentally setup one repo of mine successfully but cannot setup the others.

What is the right way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone may encounter this problem, the simplest way to do this is to init the git bare repo yourself in `/var/repo`, using the same directory name in phabricator (the Callsign).

Then create the corresponding diffusion in the phabricator using the Callsign. Phabricator will then import the existing repo.